# How to implement Greek symbols inside lstlisting?

Tags: symbols, listings

I just started working with LaTeX and found a small issue. I was not able to use Greek symbols (like Omega) in the `lstlisting` part. I tried different methods like `\Omega`, `$\Omega$`. But it's still not working. Please see the code below for reference. Can anyone please help?

```
   \begin{lstlisting}
        title('X[ $\Omega$ ] vs \Omega');
        ylabel('X[\Omega]');
        xlabel('\Omega');
    \end{lstlisting}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try `[mathescape]` as an optional argument to `lstlistings`.

Comment: Try to set escape delimiters, e.g. `(*` and `*)` via `lstset{escapeinside={(*}{*)}}` and then inside `lstlisting` environment insert a math expression, such as `$\Omega$` between defined delimiters, for instance  `\begin{lstlisting} (*$\Omega$*) \end{lstlisting}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listings` allows setting delimiters that let you run LaTeX code inside. This is done via `escapeinside={<opening delimniter>}{<closing delimiter>}` in the command `\lstset{}`. For instance, I have defined both opening and closing delimiters as `(*` and `*)`, respectively.

The MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  escapeinside={(*}{*)},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
    title('X[ (*$\Omega$*) ] vs \Omega');
    ylabel('X[\Omega]');
    xlabel('\Omega');
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

EDIT

Another and simpler solution is to escape math expressions and add `\lstset{mathescape}` instead of the one with delimiters. Then, the code would work just as you type. Example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{mathescape}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
    title('X[ $\Omega$ ] vs \Omega');
    ylabel('X[\Omega]');
    xlabel('\Omega');
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```